# Array checkbox show a new div

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have some problems with a JavaScript code, because I show a new div if the person checked a checkbox, but if a checked another checkbox the div should disappear, but it does, here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkDisplay = function(check, form) { //check ID, form ID
        form = document.getElementById(form), check = document.getElementById(check);
        check.onclick = function(){
            form.style.display = (this.checked) ? "block" : "none";
            form.reset();
        };
        check.onclick();
    };
</script>
```

And this is the block of HTML:

```
<div id="Opciones">
        <p style="display: inline-block;">Efectivo</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="efe" name="check"/>
        <p style="display: inline-block;">Deposito</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="depo" name="check"/>
    </div>

    <div id="deposi">
        <div class="row">
             <input type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    checkDisplay("depo", "deposi");
</script>
```

just one of the checboxes should be marked, if is checked depo checkbox open a new div with a new imput and another things, but if a cheked efe chechbox the div that appeared before should be dissapear, In short, if a checkbox should appear within a form, but if under another, should disappear.

the problem become when shows the div, if i select the other checkbox the form does not disappear

Please... I need help with this code... If you have another code that be great!

Comment: Will you clarify your intended goal? What if the second box is checked, but not the first? What if both boxes are checked? Do you also plan to update the status of one or the other checkbox in certain cases?

Comment: Additionally, instead of "_plis i need help with this code..._" please consider explaining why this code doesn't work and what you expect to happen.

Comment: ok sorry... just one of the checboxes should be marked, if is checked depo checkbox open a new div with a new imput and another things, but if a cheked efe chechbox the div that appeared before should be dissapear, In short, if a checkbox should appear within a form, but if under another, should disappear.

Comment: the problem become when shows the div, if i select the other checkbox the form does not disappear

Comment: Will you update your question to show the code that attempts to implement _all_ of those things and update the last paragraph to tell exactly how the current code does not fulfill your expectations?

Comment: Dude... You have mentioned document.GetelementbyId(Form) and (Check).. so where are those ID's in html...

Comment: are passed in this line, in here here specific form and check  <script type="text/javascript">
    checkDisplay("depo", "deposi");
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is create an  and a  and be related in a javascript to show when the value is the same and hide when it changes

```
><select name="status" id="status">
>    <option value="">pick one...</option>
>    <option value="show">show</option>
>    <option value="hide">hide</option>
></select>
><div name="razordiv" id="razordiv">Hi!</div>
><script>$(document).ready(function() {
>        $("#razondiv").hide();
>        $("#status").change(function() {
>           if ($("#status").val() == 'show') {
>               $("#razondiv").show();
>           }
>           else {
>               $("#razondiv").hide();
>           }
>        });
>     });
></script>
```